# Verify my proof: $\bigcup \{A \setminus B | A \in \mathcal F \} \subseteq \bigcup (\mathcal F \setminus \mathscr P(B)) $

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, proof-writing

I'm self learning from the book "How to Prove it" by Velleman (3rd edition). I don't have access to a math professor, so I need a little help from the community. Please verify my proof.

Problem 15 pag. 140

> Suppose $B$ is a set and $\mathcal F$ is a family of sets. Prove that $\bigcup \{A \setminus B | A \in \mathcal F \}  \subseteq \bigcup (\mathcal F \setminus \mathscr P(B)) $.

**Proof**. Let's introduce the following notations: $C = \bigcup \{A \setminus B | A \in \mathcal F \}$ and $D = \bigcup (\mathcal F \setminus \mathscr P(B)) $. So $C$ contains all the elements which are members of sets from $\mathcal F$ , but none of them are members of $B$. The set $D$ also contains elements which are members of sets from $F$, but if there is a set $G \in \mathcal F$ and $G \subseteq B$, then elements of $G$ are not part of D. In the same time $D$ can contain elements from $B$, if there is a set $H \in \mathcal F$ and there is $z \in H$ and $w \in H$, but $z \in B$ and $w \notin B$. Now it is clear that any element of $C$ is also an element of $D$ and the relation $C \subseteq D$ is satisfied. $\blacksquare$

Comment: Why -1 ?? I just posted the question and got -1 within a few seconds.

Comment: Why isn't your first sentence:  "Let $x$ be an arbitrary element of $\bigcup \{A \setminus B \mid A \in \mathcal{F}\}$"?  You have made your proof much more complicated than necessary by not starting this way.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write a natural-language proof, then you still need to make your statements unambiguous and your steps clear, and I wouldn't say either is true right now.

For instance, take this part:

> The set $D$ also contains elements which are members of sets from $F$, but if there is a set $G \in \mathcal F$ and $G \subseteq B$, then elements of $G$ are not part of D.

If I interpret "then element of $G$ are not part of $D$" literally, you seem to be saying $$D = \left(\bigcup\mathcal{F}\right) \setminus \left(\bigcup(\mathcal{F}\cap\mathcal{P}(B))\right),$$ but this isn't necessarily true.  And yes, I know what you're actually trying to say (that $G$ doesn't itself contribute elements to $D$), but by this point in the proof, I don't know why you're stating it.

Then you follow it up with

> In the same time $D$ can contain elements from $B$, if there is a set $H \in \mathcal F$ and there is $z \in H$ and $w \in H$, but $z \in B$ and $w \notin B$.

This would be an excellent comment **after** the proof to illustrate why the reverse inclusion doesn't necessarily hold true, but it's placement in the proof just makes your logical steps confused.

> Now it is clear that any element of $C$ is also an element of $D$

While I do appreciate your removal of "obviously clear," the word "clear" has the same problem.  It's only use here is to stand in for the logical steps you didn't actually justify.  A good test for whether something is *actually* clear is whether removing "it is clear that" leaves an argument that *is* clear.  In order to check this, let's make the above edits and see how the argument reads:

> Let's introduce the following notations: $C = \bigcup \{A \setminus B | A \in \mathcal F \}$ and $D = \bigcup (\mathcal F \setminus \mathscr P(B)) $. So $C$ contains all the elements which are members of sets from $\mathcal F$ , but none of them are members of $B$. The set $D$ also contains elements which are members of sets from $F$, but if there is a set $G \in \mathcal F$ and $G \subseteq B$, then $G$ doesn't contribute elements to $D$. Now any element of $C$ is also an element of $D$ and the relation $C \subseteq D$ is satisfied.

You may argue whether my version of the proof is favorable to you, but what it looks like to me is that you have two statements describing $C$ and $D$ separately, and the first time they're mentioned together is when you state that $C$ is a subset of $D$, which is just what you're supposed to be proving.

Is it hard to show that $C$ is a subset of $D$?  No, not at all, but I expect to see some steps directly relating $C$ to $D$ prior to the statement of the conclusion.

Comment: As a side-note, while the words "obvious" and "clear" may appear in the mathematical literature, their functional use could be more honestly represented by either "The details are left to the reader" or "By a common method," and either case isn't really appropriate for a proof you write while learning a subject.  Additionally, it's not unheard of for even well-respected professionals to state something is "obvious" only for it to be shown to be false, so it's a bad habit shared by many.